# Why is dragonglass effective against White Walkers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

**Note**: This post talks about [dragonglass](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonglass), which may reference various episodes in HBO's *Game of Thrones* (GoT). The only content that's discussed in this OP is directly related to dragonglass, which includes any conversations/events that may directly involve/mention dragonglass.

---

From what I understand, dragonglass is [obsidian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsidian). My question is, **does GoT ever actually mention *why* this glass is effective against white walkers?** Is it solely because obsidian is made at high temperatures by volcanoes (with White Walkers being "ice-like")? Or, does it have to do with the origin of White Walkers, with respect to the Children of the Forest?

> A long-forgotten secret is that the Children [of the Forest] actually created the White Walkers as a weapon, by transforming humans into them: this was achieved in a magic ceremony that involved (among other things) plunging a dragonglass shard into a human's chest.

Perhaps, due to the ceremony involving dragonglass, the White Walkers now have a negative affinity towards it?

Aside from these two theories, I've got nothing.. can anyone help in explaining this?

Comment: Not explained yet. Any answer will be speculation (opinion based).

Comment: For your information, it's more accurate to say dragonglass is *similar* to non-fictional obsidian, but not that it *is* obsidian. We don't yet exactly know what the process of creating dragonglass is - many speculate that, as the name indicates, it involves dragon fire, not a volcanic process. The same is true for "dragon steel" (aka Valyrian steel), which is also effective against White Walkers - so we can infer that dragons are at the root of this.

Comment: Could be related to the heat, could be magical, could be a weakness put in by the children of the forest, could just be a plot point with no explanation. We don't know yet.

Comment: It is like why we breath oxygen only?

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with Dragon Fire. Dragon Glass and Valyrian Steel (Dragon Steel), can't be a coincidence. I would probably go on to say that Dragon breath must have been involved in the creation of both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the *Game of Thrones* universe obsidian has magical properties that it obviously does not have in real life, as confirmed by George R.R. Martin;

> Shaw: Is there a certain reason why they named obsidian "dragonglass" or why you did that?
>
> Martin: Yes, there is a reason.
>
> Shaw: Are dragons somehow the mortal enemy of the Others?
>
> Martin: There are a lot of legends, and you'll be hearing more about them in the future books, but a lot of stuff about Others and about dragons maybe isn't completely understood by the people of the present. **Obsidian is of course volcanic glass; it's formed by immense heat and pressure down in the earth. The dragons themselves are creatures of intense heat.**
>
> Shaw: I wasn't sure if you had added something to obsidian for the fantasy.
>
> Martin: **I've given it magical characteristics that of course real obsidian doesn't necessarily have. After all, we live in a world that has no magic. My world does have magic, so it's a little bit different.**
>
> *- [Interview with the Dragon, 2003,  Robert Shaw](http://web.archive.org/web/20051103091500/nrctc.edu/fhq/vol1iss3/00103009.htm/)*

Comment: Arguably, the name "dragonglass" could be derived from its ability to kill white walkers. It's a fair assumption that dragons are considered the archetypical counter to a WW. Obsidian is the only material known to kill the WW without a real connection to dragons (Valyrian steel is rumored to be forged by **dragonfire**, thus being directly connected to dragons). Even if obsidian has no relation to dragons whatsoever, they can share a name because they share one (unrelated but coincidental) characteristic: killing White Walkers.

Comment: @Flater There were no dragons in Westeros during the Long Night or used in the War for the Dawn. I don't believe dragons were a known opponent to White Walkers until recently... There might a new question there...

Comment: That supports my claim that dragonglass is a _recent_ name (relative to the Long Night) and essentially nothing more than a nickname, and not the basis for why obsidian is effective in the first place.

Comment: @Flater - I always felt that it was called dragonglass because it looked like whatever’s left over after dragons have melted one’s castle.

Comment: @Obie2.0: What you say is also possible (mine is just a theory), but your example still somewhat confirms the main purpose of my comment: that dragonglass has no _actual_ connection to dragons; which would mean that its ability to kill white walkers is unrelated to dragonfire's ability to kill white walkers (they both **just happen** to work)